# Arshaw Timezone issue

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar

I am using Arshaw fullcalendar plugin version 1.5.3,

The problem is I created an event at 9AM with the local machine timezone EST (Eastern Time) and when I change my local machine timezone to IST, then the event appear at different time 7:30 PM in the calendar.

It works perfectly fine for EASTERN timezone and if changed then the records appear in wrong timing.

Please help I have tried to initialize `ignoreTimezone` to false and updated the version but nothing seems to help.

```js
// initialize the fullcalendar and set ignore timezone to false 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: {
            url: 'http://www.google.com/your_feed_url/',
            className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
            currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
        },
        ignoreTimezone: false 
     });
});  

/* Passing the event to fullcalendar to display the slots in calendar properly 
   It accepts the start and end time in timestamp */

event.id = appId;
event.start = startTime;    // 1389358800 timestamp
event.end = endTime;        // 1389359700 timestamp
event.editable = presentEvent;
event.allDay = false;
event.patient_name = patient_name;

events.push(event);

_ac.fullCalendar('addEventSource',events);
```

It works properly for a Eastern time zone and the slot appear properly at 8:00 AM (Start Time) - 8:15 AM (End time)

When I changed the local timezone to IST then the slot appears at 6:30 PM (Start Time) to 6.45PM (End time)

Comment: Please show us *exactly* the code for the configuration options you have used.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: {
                    url: 'http://www.google.com/your_feed_url/',
                    className: 'gcal-event',           // an option!
                    currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
                    
                },
                ignoreTimezone: false 
              });
            });

Comment: Please *edit* your question.  Code is terribly hard to read in comments.  You'll need to show more than that anyway.  Show enough code to reproduce the problem.  Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Matt Johnson , I have posted the code, Please help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/):

> Sometimes it can be confusing as to why FullCalendar displays event times differently than the Google Calendar interface. There are the two factors involved in this:
>
> - *the calendar's timezone*, accessed through "Calendar settings" after clicking the arrow next to the calendar's name
> - *your Google Account's timezone*, accessed through the "Settings" link at the top right of the Google Calendar screen (near the "Sign out" link)
>
> When both timezones are the same, you should have no problems. When they are different, FullCalendar will display times in the *calendar's* timezone. Thus, times will be different than what you see in the Google Calendar interface because they are being adjusted to the GMT of the calendar. The solution is to use the `currentTimezone` option. If this is set to the same timezone as your Google Account, all dates should appear consistent.

Since you have asked Google calendar for the `America/Chicago` time zone, the values you are getting back are starting in US Central time (*not Eastern*), and then converted to GMT as numeric timestamps.

If your calendar is actually in IST (India Standard Time), then you should request the time zone as `Asia/Kolkata` instead.

Since you are using numeric Unix timestamps and not parsing ISO date strings, you do not need the `ignoreTimezone` option ([see the documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/)).  It will not affect the outcome either way, so you can remove it.

Comment: The initialization code for ignoreTimezone and currentTimezone doesnt work at all .. even if i remove the code it doesnt make any difference .. 

The data,  Start Time and End time which i am using is coming from database and it is proper.

The problem is of machine's timezone it works fine with the Eastern timezone and if changed to any other timezone the slot on calendar get changed to other timings. 

Data remains the same but the outputs completely get changed based on the timezone

Comment: what i want is no matter what timezone user is using in his/her machine .. the records entered in the database should be shown properly in calendar .. 

Consider an eg : A user takes an appointment of 8am to 8.15am with the machine's timezone Eastern time and then the user sitting in india is viewing the same appointment and it is showing on 6.30pm -6.45pm ... Which is wrong 
This is happening due to the timezone difference .. Indian user is using Indian standard time and the US guy is using Eastern timezone

Both are viewing the same appointment and data remains the same in database

Comment: AM I  passing the data to 

_ac.fullCalendar('addEventSource',events);  in a wrong way ? or there is any other alternative .. Coz the data remains the same in both the scenario only the machine's timezone is changed and due to this the appointment slots are coming in different time .. 

Please help me out .. this is causing a big problem for me

Comment: Matt .. can you help me out?

Comment: Look at the [docs for the `Event` object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).  If you are passing a unix timestamp (like 1389358800), of course that will be adjusted to local time.  That's just how JavaScript `Date` works.  Try using an ISO8601 string instead, like "2014-01-10T8:00:00".  Then when `ignoreTimezone` is true it should display 8:00 regardless of the user's time zone.